# Add values from multidimensional array to another array

Tags: php, arrays

Hello good morning wherever you are :D, i have a lil problem, i have this code of arrays
$arrayToView is the info of every single user that i want.
$tagsArray are only tags that use every user but i need to merge all the info something like the last array...

```
$arrayToView = array(
    'IVOFACUNDO' = array(
         'mails' => 3,
         'contacts' => 34,
         'blocked' => 23
     ),
     'ESRAYCU' = array(
         'mails' => 23,
         'contacts' => 124,
         'blocked' => 44
     )
)
```

And i have another one like this

```
$tagsArray= array(
    'IVOFACUNDO' = array(
         '14' => array(
             'id' => 14,
             'name' => 'php',
             'value' => 1
         ),
         '15' => array(
             'id' => 15,
             'name' => 'javascript',
             'value' => 1
         )
     ),
     'ESRAYCU' = array(
         '1' => array(
             'id' => 1,
             'name' => 'python',
             'value' => 1
         ),
         '15'=> array(
             'id' => 15,
             'name' => 'javascript',
             'value' => 1
         )
     )
)
```

so the question is how i can merge both arrays obviously respectively with the same admin something like this

```
$arrayToView = array(
    'IVOFACUNDO' = array(
         'mails' => 3,
         'contacts' => 34,
         'blocked' => 23,
         'tags' => array(
             '14' => array(
                 'id' => 14,
                 'name' => 'php',
                 'value' => 1
             ),
             '15' => array(
                 'id' => 15,
                 'name' => 'javascript',
                 'value' => 1
             )
         )
     ),
     'ESRAYCU' = array(
         'mails' => 23,
         'contacts' => 124,
         'blocked' => 44,
         'tags' => array(
             '1' => array(
                 'id' => 1,
                 'name' => 'python',
                 'value' => 1
             ),
             '15'=> array(
                 'id' => 15,
                 'name' => 'javascript',
                 'value' => 1
             )
         )
     )
)
```

The key 'tags' need to be created in the merge of every iteration to add and get one array with all the values, how i can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this snippet.

```
foreach($arrayToView as $key => $arr){
   if(array_key_exists($key, $tagsArray)){
       $arrayToView[$key]['tags'] = $tagsArray[$key];
   }
}
echo '<pre>';print_r($arrayToView);echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Yo bro your answer works perfectly and the answer of @jack also!! thank you so much!!

Comment: great! it helps.. plz mark as answer. might someone also find it useful..

Answer (score 1):

Use php inbuilt function

```
$result_Arr = array_merge_recursive($arrayToView,$tagsArray);
```

Comment: Yo bro your answer works perfectly and the answer of @Arbaz Khan also!! thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$arrayToView = array(
    'IVOFACUNDO' => array(
         'mails' => 3,
         'contacts' => 34,
         'blocked' => 23
     ),
     'ESRAYCU' => array(
         'mails' => 23,
         'contacts' => 124,
         'blocked' => 44
     )
);

$tagsArray= array(
    'IVOFACUNDO' => array(
         '14' => array(
             'id' => 14,
             'name' => 'php',
             'value' => 1
         ),
         '15' => array(
             'id' => 15,
             'name' => 'javascript',
             'value' => 1
         )
     ),
     'ESRAYCU' => array(
         '1' => array(
             'id' => 1,
             'name' => 'python',
             'value' => 1
         ),
         '15'=> array(
             'id' => 15,
             'name' => 'javascript',
             'value' => 1
         )
     )
);

foreach($arrayToView as $key => $value){
    if(isset($tagsArray[$key])){
        $arrayToView[$key]['tags'] = array();
        foreach($tagsArray[$key] as $key2 => $value2){
            $arrayToView[$key]['tags'][$key2] = $tagsArray[$key][$key2];
        }

    }   
}



echo'<pre>';
print_r($arrayToView);
echo'</pre>';
?>
```